# Is "The earrings of which I lost at the theatre yesterday were not my favourite ones" sound?

Tags: relative-clauses

Neither of the options below seems suitable for the sentence.

> The earrings _______ I lost at the theatre yesterday were not my favourite ones.
>
> a) which is
> b) where
> c) —
> d) of which

(Yes, *C* is supposed to be empty.)

I have the same doubts about this one.

> We as teachers usually take a short vacation in February ____ there is no work for us to do.
>
> a) on which
> b) in which
> c) of which
> d) —

I can't tell if relative-clauses apply in these sentences.

Answer (score 2):

Relative clauses can be used in both situations, but the specific ones used in the answers are all wrong.

I think technically he first one should be C in order to avoid splitting the subject and verb (I am not certain about this, but I feel like that was a thing I learned in grammar school).

I.E.
"The earrings I lost yesterday at the theater were not my favorite ones."

One could use a relative clause here, but I think it would be grammatically incorrect (it wouldn't really sound that unnatural though):

E.G.
"The earrings, which I lost at the theater yesterday, were not my favorite ones."

The second one would be best written as:

"As teachers, we usually take a short vacation in February, when there is no work for us to do."

Comment: One would have to use "that" for the earrings unless they had already been specified.